# What economical motherboard best supports upgrading AMD Ryzen 5 3400G to Ryzen 9 3950X in the future?

Tags: motherboard, upgrade, ryzen

A few firsts here. This is my first question on SE (so also first question on Hardware Recommendations), and also my first computer build, so feel free to correct me if I'm off-base! That said, I am an electrical engineer, so also feel free to be a bit technical if you must.

I'm choosing parts for a new computer build, and I especially like the new Ryzen processors' performance/price ratio. I'm designing with the intent to upgrade the processor in the future. Starting out, I want to use the AMD Ryzen 5 3400G (4 cores) with only the internal graphics card. Stage 2 is upgrading the graphics card to something discrete; I haven't picked which yet. Stage 3 is upgrading my processor to something very nice - an AMD Ryzen 9 3950X (16 cores), for example.

Why three stages? I'm willing to swallow the cost off the Ryzen 5 3400G to have a working computer while I save up and select graphics cards, wait for the 3950X to fall a bit in price, etc.

My question: **What economical motherboard would be a good fit for this scenario?**

Cheaper is better, but I don't want to bottleneck performance. X570 chipset is a must. At least 32GB RAM is a must. M.2 PCIE/NVME drive compatibility is a must - I'm so looking forward to 3GB/s transfer speeds!

I don't need RGB lights or water cooling; not for my first build, at least. ;) I'm intending to edit RAW photos in a program that likes having lots of threads.

I've looked around and found the MSI MPG X570 GAMING PLUS ATX AM4 Motherboard, which seems compatible on PC Part Picker, but I'm worried that there will be some performance throttling that the site doesn't mention when I put a beast like the 3950X on it. Is that something I need to worry about with this board?

Note: I know this question is similar to [this recent post](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/motherboard-for-the-long-run-in-an-otherwise-initially-low-end-gaming-system), but given the difference in hardware (AMD vs. Intel, for one), I'm guessing it's not a duplicate?

Note 2: If the question as stated is too subjective, I'd be happy just to know "**Does the MSI MPG X570 GAMING PLUS ATX AM4 Motherboard throttle performance of the AMD Ryzen 9 3950X?**"

Thanks!

**Edit:** Given that this is my first question, if I can improve it, please let me know how in the comments.

Comment: You can see x570 motherboard reviews on YouTube by hardware unboxed and by Gamer Nexus then decide at own